# How to read multiple integers from string

Tags: c++, string

INPUT:

```
Mint Ice Cream      6 80
```

CODE:

```
int IntAmount=2;
string line, name, data;
ifstream fd('Input.txt);

getline(fd, line);
name=line.substr(0, 20); // name="Mint Ice Cream      "
data=line.substr(20);    // data ="6 80"

for(int i=0; i<IntAmount; i++){

   // code that reads N[i] integer by integer from string called data

}
```

I got some integers stored in the same string `data`. How do I extract them into array `N[i]` if I know there are `IntAmount` of them? I know that I can read the Input in much more basic way, but this is just very simplified input.

Comment: Stopped reading at `('Input.txt)`.

Comment: Rip, it should have been `("Input.txt")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following function will do the job for you:

```
int string_to_int(char const *input_str, std::size_t count)
{
 int result_integer = 0;
 std::size_t i = 0 ;
 if ( input_str[0] == '+' || input_str[0] == '-' ) 
      ++i;
 while(i < count)
 {
      if ( input_str[i] >= '0' && input_str[i] <= '9' )
      {
          int val = (input_str[0] == '-') ? ('0' - input_str[i] ) : (input_str[i]-'0');
          result_integer = result_integer * 10 + val;
      }
      else
          throw std::invalid_argument("invalid string input");
      i++;
 }
 return result_integer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: nevermind I thought it was C#

<strike>You could split the `data` string into multiple strings as such `data.Split(' ')` (which splits it at the `' '`-character) and then for each substring it returns you can use the function `int.Parse(<substring here>)` to get the integer equivalent for it.</strike>